# How to get object key when using aggregation binding in OpenUI5

Tags: sapui5

For example, I have an `sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel` initialized with the following data:

```json
{
    "data": {
        "something": {"a": "blah", "b": "blah", "c": "blah"},
        "another": {"a": "blah", "b": "blah", "c": "blah"}
    }
}
```

And I have a `sap.m.List` in XMLView like this:

```xml
<List items="{/data}">
    <items>
        <ObjectListItem title="{a}" intro="">
            <firstStatus>
                <ObjectStatus title="{b}" text="{c}"/>
            </firstStatus>
        </ObjectListItem>
    </items>
</List>
```

Now I want the `intro` property of these two `ObjectListItem` to be "something" and "another", but I can't find a way to do it except changing the data to

```json
{
    "data": {
        "something": {"key": "something", "a": "blah", "b": "blah", "c": "blah"},
        "another": {"key": "another", "a": "blah", "b": "blah", "c": "blah"}
    }
}
```

and then bind `"{key}"`, which seems pretty stupid (it introduces redundancies and wastes server bandwidth).

So, any idea?

Comment: How do you do aggregation binding with `/data` in the first place if it doesn't return an array but an object?

Comment: @boghyon I don't know. But last I test, it is possible. It works like for...in loop in javascript I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a custom factory function, getting the key you want from the context path:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>MVC with XmlView</title>

  <!-- Load UI5, select "blue crystal" theme and the "sap.m" control library -->
  <script id='sap-ui-bootstrap'
    src='https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js'
   data-sap-ui-theme='sap_bluecrystal'
   data-sap-ui-libs='sap.m'
   data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax='complex'></script>

  <script id="view1" type="sapui5/xmlview">
      <mvc:View
    controllerName="my.own.controller"
    xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"
    xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    xmlns:f="sap.ui.layout.form"
    xmlns="sap.m">
       <List items="{path:'/data', factory: '.myFactory'}">
          </List>
   </mvc:View>
 </script>


  <script>
   // define a new (simple) Controller type
   sap.ui.controller("my.own.controller", {
     myFactory: function(sId, oContext){
       var keyPath = oContext.getPath();
       console.log(oContext);
       
       var oObjectListItem = new sap.m.ObjectListItem({
         title: {path: keyPath + '/a'},
         intro: keyPath.split('/')[keyPath.split('/').length - 1],
         firstStatus: [
           new sap.m.ObjectStatus({
             title: {path: keyPath + '/b'},
             text: {path: keyPath + '/c'}
           })
         ]
       });
       
       return oObjectListItem;
     }
   });

   // instantiate the View
   var myView = sap.ui.xmlview({viewContent:jQuery('#view1').html()}); // accessing the HTML inside the script tag above

   // create some dummy JSON data
   var data = {
          "data": {
              "something": {"a": "blah", "b": "blah", "c": "blah"},
              "another": {"a": "blah", "b": "blah", "c": "blah"}
          }
      }
   
   // create a Model and assign it to the View
   var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
   oModel.setData(data);
   myView.setModel(oModel);
   
   
   // put the View onto the screen
   myView.placeAt('content');

  </script>
 
 </head>
 <body id='content' class='sapUiBody'>
 </body>
</html>
```